# Blender rendering as wireframe

Tags: cycles-render-engine, wireframe

When I render an image in Blender, it appears as a wireframe. Does anyone know how to fix this?

3D viewport (render preview):
[image: 3D viewport (render preview)]
3D viewport (material preview):
[image: 3D viewport (material preview)]
Render:
[image: Render]

Comment: Please use the built in image adding system to put images in your question. As is, yeah that is weird. My first thought is that you enabled workbench render, or possibly have something configured with freestyle rendering that’s doing this.

Comment: @TheLabCat I don't have workbench render or freestyle render enabled.

Comment: Apple Wireframe modifier.

Comment: Can you upload the file?